# cookbook in computational geometry / map overlay algorithm implementation

Tags: computational-geometry

is there any good cookbook or handbook with C snippet code for computational geometry?

I was looking specifically for Map Overlay algorithm.
I've seen the INRIA library CGAL (inside i mean) but is too "engineerized" for a primer like me.

Comment: C or C++, either are good.